# Using a linux server to forward an RDP connection between LAN and VPN interface

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, forwarding, cisco-anyconnect

**Update:** I now need a solution to this problem ASAP. I sort of understand that I could probably set something up in `iptables` for NAT and port forwarding but I really don't know enough about the tool or its syntax to come up with my own rules.

- I have a machine with a static IP on my local network: `192.168.1.166`. (A Hyper-V VM running Debian 10)
- The machine runs Cisco AnyConnect to connect to my work VPN.
  This VPN client sets up a 2nd network interface so that I have two:
  `eth0` (my LAN), and `cscotun0`
- I want to be able to put `192.168.1.166` into the RDP client on my personal desktop and have it connect through the VM to the remote desktop at my work.

The only question I *really* need answered:

**How can I route TCP & UDP connections on port 3389 from my personal desktop, though the VM, to the remote system at work?**

I'm guessing that the VM needs to "masquerade" the RDP connection as if were coming from the VPN client which gets a dynamic IP on the work network, so I know that I need NAT. Is the `masquerade` tool also necessary for that?

---

**Original Question:**

I need to use RDP over a Cisco AnyConnect full-tunnel VPN for work from home.

The IT department at my work hasn't configured the VPN server to support split-tunnel for just RDP, and I may find myself needing other network services at work anyways so I would like to work around using a full-tunnel connection. However, I don't want to use AnyConnect VPN client on my personal computer since I am under the impression that would route *all* of my internet traffic through the VPN as well.

I have set up a Debian 10 virtual machine that is running the VPN client. I want to have this VM masquerade as the remote RDP server on my LAN. That way I could avoid running the VPN client on my personal computer and just connect with the RDP client to the VM, which then forwards the RDP connection over the VPN to the actual RDP server.

So, how can I accomplish this?

I only have administrative access to:

- My Windows 10 desktop at home.
- My "proxy" VM
- My home router
- My Windows 10 desktop at work. (Although IT can block/undo any changes I make if they are a security risk)

I am currently using a combination of VNC and RDP to hop through the VM for remote desktop, but it is limited in resolution by the VM hypervisor and combining the disadvantages of both protocols.

Comment: Does your "proxy" VM use Cisco AnyConnect or does it use OpenConnect?

Comment: @user1686, I have a shell script called `anyconnect-linux64-4.6.01103-core-vpn-webdeploy-k9.sh` that my work provides to set up Cisco AnyConnect on linux. 100% certain the client is "AnyConnect".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your VM `192.168.1.166` has access to both networks (your local network and the corporate network via VPN), then use [`socat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat) to establish a bidirectional tunnel between your VM and the corporate RDP server. On the VM run this:

```
socat tcp4-listen:3389,reuseaddr,fork tcp:remote-addr:3389
```

This will open TCP port `3389` on your VM and any TCP traffic that arrives there will be tunneled to the `remote-addr:3389`.

Socat also supports UDP.

The option `reuseaddr` is described in the man page as follows:

> Allows other sockets to bind to an address even if parts of it (e.g.
> the local port) are already in use by socat

It enables the `socat` to restart and bind to the specified port immediately.

The option `fork` has the following effect:

> After establishing a connection, handles its channel in a child
> process and keeps the parent process attempting to produce more
> connections

Without this option the `socat` will terminate after the connection it handles terminates and the `socat` will need to be restarted (either manually or with a script). With this option the `socat` will continue to listen and serve incoming connections without termination.

In this way you can specify `192.168.1.166` as an RDP server on your personal desktop and the traffic will be tunneled to the corporate server.

Comment: And with such a simple one-liner I'm up and running. Thank you so much!

Comment: And you've probably circumvented any security policy your company has set up.

Comment: The quality of this connection is low, since there is no UDP. I tried UDP connection but UDP process is killed, I randomly tried `ignoreeof` as well `fork` neither worked