# Can I route host traffic through a VPN configured in a VM?

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine, vpn, hyper-v

To access network resources for my company, I need to set up a VPN on a company-managed OS. I'm using my personal laptop to work, and don't want to have it be managed by my company, so I created a VM and configured the VPN on it. My current workflow involves remote desktoping into the VM and using that as my work environment. This VPN allows access to both company resources and the general internet.

The problem with that is that there's some latency with RDP into the VM (and I often have to RDP from that VM into some computer on my company's network, which compounds the latency). So I'm wondering if there's a way to configure the VPN on the VM, but use it from the host OS. In that world, I'd be able to access my company's network directly from the host OS, with all connections being tunneled through VM.

Is it possible to route host network traffic through the VM?

The host and VM are running Windows 11 on amd64. This is a Hyper-V VM.

Comment: If you can make it work, the VM connection would have to be bridged, so your host is involved anyway.  I have used Company VPN access lots. What is your true concern.

Comment: I do something similar for working from home and got a helpful answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1531047/using-a-linux-server-to-forward-an-rdp-connection-between-lan-and-vpn-interface). I have a VM with the company VPN client installed to ensure that my host traffic isn't going through it by default (it's not split tunnel). I use RDP from my host to a workstation in the office as if it was a split tunnel for just RDP.

Comment: If you have admin access on the VM, then it's doable with some awkward virtual routing. "I'm using my personal laptop to work, and don't want to have it be managed by my company" sure seems like a quick way to get fired if not explicitly allowed by IT policy